Tee only STDERR in Powershell without red text
I am using powershell to run a program (pyinstaller) writes all of its progress output to STDERR. I want the output of this command to be both printed on to the console AND saved to a file.
First, I used this:  COMMAND | tee compile.log. Everything looked good on the console, but the log file was empty. So, I tried this: COMMAND 2>&1 | tee compile.log. This caused the log file to be written properly, but it caused huge issues:

All output on the console was in the red error colour.
No matter if the command was successful, the exit code states that an error has occured.

So, is there something I can use that will both display the progress in the console and write it to a file, but not look like an error?

Could somebody please provide a comment as to why this question should be downvoted?

Not the downvoter but my guess would be due to the difficulty in helping you since we literally know nothing about the "annoying program" you're running.

@DougMaurer OK. The program is pyinstaller, which is annoying because it outputs only on stderr.

Instead of mentioning it in a comment you should [edit] your question to update it with all needed details. And since the program you have issues with is related to Python you may add the according tag to your question. This could trigger someone actually having experiences with it. ☝

$PSStyle.OutputRendering = 'PlainText' perhaps helps


All output on the console was in the red error colour

That is because you only capturing the second (2) Error Stream.
That stream produces ErrorRecords:
$Output = Write-Error 'Something went wrong' 2>&1
$Output.GetType().FullName
System.Management.Automation.ErrorRecord

That are colored by PowerShell's default display view defined by this property script:
$FormatData = Get-FormatData System.Management.Automation.ErrorRecord
$FormatData.FormatViewDefinition.Control.Entries.CustomItems.Expression.Value

(For details see the answer on: How does Powershell know which property to Print out by Default)
To suppress the red ANSI codes you might simply pipe the output to the Out-String cmdlet as it lets the FormatViewDefinition script belief it writes to something that doesn't support ANSI:
Write-Error 'Something went wrong' 2>&1 | tee compile.log | Out-String

To capture all (not only the red ErrorRecord) streams, use the asterisk:
Write-Error 'Something went wrong' *>&1 | tee compile.log | Out-String


The other issue is probably unrelated to the above and indeed too vague for an answer. If that part is still a concern, I would suggest to open a separate question for that, with more details about with Exit Codes you actually get and which exit codes you expect and how you try to capture them.
